# Subtracting a week from firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How would I go about subtracting a week from a `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()` timestamp? I have different documents that have a timestamp, and I need to build a function that would check if any of those documents have a timestamp older than 7 days. Heck, maybe there is a built in function to check if a date is "expired"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: depends on the precision, but you could just take the seconds from the timestamp and subtract a week (604800)? Or use the builtin ```toDate()``` https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate method and a library like date-fns to compare the javascript date objects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As defined [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/50195991a514d16ee40d08fe32d308111f7917e3/packages/firestore/src/lite/timestamp.ts#L44-L46),

```
firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()
```

is the equivalent of

```
firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now())
```

To get a week old timestamp, you would use:

```
// 1 week in ms = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 = 604800000

const nowTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now();
const weekOldTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(nowTimestamp.toMillis() - 604800000);
// or the shorter
const weekOldTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now() - 604800000);
```

Let's say you have the following document in a collection called `/photos`:

```js
{
  "title": "My Photo",
  "desc": "This is the first photo I uploaded here",
  "storageRef": "/userData/userid1/uploads/89q24u2q98y23.png",
  "thumbnailRef": "/userData/userid1/uploads/89q24u2q98y23.thumbnail.png",
  "createdAt": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
}
```

If you wanted to find all photos that were older than a week, you would use, either of the following identical statements:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("photos")
  .where("createdAt", "<", new Date(Date.now() - 604800000))
  .get()
```

or

```
const weekAgoTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now() - 604800000);

firebase.firestore().collection("photos")
  .where("createdAt", "<", weekAgoTimestamp)
  .get()
```

If you had copy of the document already, from a query like this:

```
const aPhotoSnapshot = await firebase.firestore()
  .doc("photos/somePhotoId")
  .get();
```

and you wanted to check if it was older than a week, you would use:

```
const createdAtTimestamp = aPhotoSnapshot.get("createdAt");
const isWeekOld = createdAtTimestamp.toMillis() < Date.now() - 604800000;
```